# Open api generator : change Client name

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am using the "OpenApi generator" to create the client library for an api.

```
openapi-generator generate -i https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/openapi/en-us/product/2-0/openapi.yaml -g ruby -o tmp/test/custom_name
```

This generate a class "OpenapiClient" but I need to change this name to "CustomApiClient". How can I pass this value?
This seems to me a standard thing to do, why is not so immediate? Am I following the best practice?

```
# Load the gem
require 'openapi_client'

# Setup authorization
OpenapiClient.configure do |config|
  # Configure Bearer authorization: bearer
  config.access_token = 'YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed way harder to find than it should have been, but if you run `openapi-generator config-help -g ruby`, it will show you all the options for ruby client configurations. Specifically, `gemName`. So you can simply create a config file like:

```yaml
# config.yaml
gemName: custom_api_client
```

and provide `-c /path/to/your/config.yaml` when running the generate command.

Comment: any idea how can I do same for Java name ? I do have ApiClient.java generated and I want to change to CustomApiClient.java ?

Comment: Same thing but use java instead of ruby `openapi-generator config-help -g java`